# how to connect Centos server to the outside world

Tags: linux-networking, local-area-network

I configured the eth0 interface to receive network-connection from my iMac to wich this computer is connected to with an ethernetcable. Configure is a big word here since I only changed the ONBOOT key to yes.

The Centos computer running Nginx has to receive requests from outside the LAN, if I type an address in the browser on my Imac. The iMac is connected to a wireless router from the ISP.

How would you set it up?

thanks

Comment: There is not enough information here to solve your particular problem. Also, you might need a systems administrator if this is any kind of professional environment.

Comment: what more information do I have to include?

Comment: 1. check if both interfaces on Centos and iMac are configured in a right way.
2. check if both are UP
3. check if you can ping Centos from iMac
4. check if you can access Centos Web server locally.
5. check firewall rules on CentOS.
Good Luck!

Comment: I did not install any firewall with Centos minimal and I can ping the IP. Do not know about point 1, and 4 yet, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to:

- configure port forwarding on your ISP router to forward incoming connections from the WAN to OS X. (How depends on your make/model of router).

Then:

- turn on Internet Sharing in OS X, to make the CentOS machine able to get to the world
- configure port forwarding through to CentOS on OS X, to make the world able to get to the CentOS machine
- maybe modify the firewall rules on OS X to allow the above connections

Explained here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-configure-macosx-as-nat-router/

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at that link. That's it for now then.